# Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data

Tags: installation, magento2.4.2

i am trying to install magento 2.4.2 i am facing this issue during installation
`Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Framework\Communication\Config\Data, rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, bool given` 
i have tried many ways but unable to point out what is the acutally wrong with my installation.

Comment: Visit https://magentip.com/install-magento-2-4-x-on-ubuntu-with-elasticsearch/
For install magento2.4 . There is a complete guide to install.

Answer (score 2):

I think php librarynot installed properly creating this error so you have to run this command :  sudo apt install php7.4-mcrypt

Answer (score 2):

Installing mcrypt worked for me as well.
apt install php7.4-mcrypt